# how to dynamically insert custom pages in nsis installer

Tags: installation, nsis, custom-pages

I have `installer_type` variable which will have either `desktop` or `server` as its value.

If the value is server then page1 should get inserted in the installer and page2 should be hidden for this installer and vice versa.

```
StrCmp installer_type "server" 0 +3
Page custom page1 page1Leave
Goto Done
Page custom page2 page2Leave
Done:
```

Please let me know how to achieve this in .nsi file

Answer (score 1):

The number of pages is fixed at compile time, but you can call the [`Abort`](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#abort) instruction in the page pre callback function to [skip the page](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Skipping_Pages).

Answer (score 0):

just insert when you want see it

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter2.html#2.3.2

example

if you want to see directory then license:

```
Page directory
Page license
```